# How to use up navigation with navigation components and drawer menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using a navigation drawer to swap between fragments in a `NavHostFragment`. All my destinations in the my navigation drawer are set as top destinations, so I can always access the navigation drawer from any of these fragments using `AppBarConfiguration`:

```
 Set<Integer> topLevelDestinations = new HashSet<>();
        topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.schedulesFragment);
        topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.backpacksFragment);
        topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.itemsFragment);



        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,appBarConfiguration);
```

The code is working as intended, and I can always access the hamburger button to get to the navigation drawer from any of the three top destinations, but in one of these fragments, I navigate to another fragment destination that is not in the menu drawer like this:

```
 smartPackViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(requireActivity().getApplication()).create(SmartPackViewModel.class);
        smartPackViewModel.getFoundSmartPack().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<BluetoothDevice>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
                if(navController != null){
             navController.navigate(R.id.action_backpacksFragment_to_newSmartPackFoundFragment);
                }
            }
        });
```

This code works, and as soon as I navigate to `NewSmartPackFoundFragment` the hamburger button changes to be an up button, which is what I intend. The problem is that pressing the up button doesn't take me back to the previous fragment, it doesn't do anything, and the back button doesn't do anything either. I tried overriding `onSupportNavigateUp` and because of a log I'm using I know the method is getting called, but nothing still nothing is happening:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Log.d("NAVIGATE", "onNavigateUp was called" );
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration);
    }
```

I have also tried using `navigate()` inside this method without any results:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Log.d("NAVIGATE", "onNavigateUp was called" );
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_newSmartPackFoundFragment_to_backpacksFragment2);
       return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration);
    }
```

I have looked online what the problem is, but I can't figure it out yet. This is my activity layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/logged_in_activity_drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">


         <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

             <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                 android:id="@+id/logged_in_activity_toolbar"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and these are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2"
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

**EDIT**

This is how my nav graph looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_logged_in"
    app:startDestination="@id/backpacksFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/backpacksFragment"
        android:name="com.pedroprojects.smartpack.Fragments.BackpacksFragment"
        android:label="fragment_backpacks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_backpacks"

        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_backpacksFragment_to_backpackDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/backpackDetailsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_backpacksFragment_to_newSmartPackFoundFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newSmartPackFoundFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/backpacksFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/itemsFragment"
        android:name="com.pedroprojects.smartpack.Fragments.ItemsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_items"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_items" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/schedulesFragment"
        android:name="com.pedroprojects.smartpack.Fragments.SchedulesFragment"
        android:label="fragment_schedules"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_schedules" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/backpackDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.pedroprojects.smartpack.Fragments.BackpackDetailsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_backpack_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_backpack_details" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newSmartPackFoundFragment"
        android:name="com.pedroprojects.smartpack.Fragments.NewSmartPackFoundFragment"
        android:label="fragment_new_smart_pack_found"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_smart_pack_found" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newSmartPackFoundFragment_to_backpacksFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/backpacksFragment" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `app:popUpTo` & `app:popUpToInclusive` attributes of the NavigationDrawer fragment that you use to navigate to `NewSmartPackFoundFragment`.

And you can check that directly from the navigation graph xml file under this particular fragment, and spcifically within the action that you use to go to `NewSmartPackFoundFragment` fragment which has an id of `R.id.action_backpacksFragment_to_newSmartPackFoundFragment` in your case.

Make sure that you `app:popUpToInclusive` is set to `false` to avoid clearing the navigation back-stack.

And set the `app:popUpTo` to the fragment that you want to get back when you hit the up/back button after navigating to `NewSmartPackFoundFragment`.

I will provide a sample as you didn't share the navigation graph.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/..."
    app:startDestination="@+id/...">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/backpacksFragment"
        android:name="..."
        android:label="..."
        tools:layout="..." >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_backpacksFragment_to_newSmartPackFoundFragment"
            app:destination="@id/..."
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_backpacksFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
```

> **Update 1:**
>   I tried what you suggested with the popUpTo and popUpToInclusive but I still have the same issue

Now modify `onSupportNavigateUp()` in your activity which is called whenever the user chooses to navigate Up within your application's activity hierarchy from the action bar.

Now change this method that hosts those fragments to be:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Now replace the `R.id.nav_host_fragment` with the id of the host fragment in your activity's layout

Comment: Hi Zain, thank you for your reply! I tried what you suggested with the `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` but I still have the same issue, nothing happens. I shared my navigation graph so you can take a look at it

Comment: Hi @PedroOrellana thanks for your comment! .. please check *Update 1* in answer that could be the reason

Comment: Hi @Zain, thanks for your help! I tried updating my code like that, but nothing changes...